# set the values to jquery autocomplete select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Here am written some code for set the values to jquery autocomplete select box.Below am written select box in my jsp

```
<td>ShiftId <br><select id="shiftid" class="spanValues"name="employeeshiftID" >
         <option value="">-----Select-----</option>
```

And shiftid values are coming from database 
append the values to select box have written some code 
But it is not appended, input box values is appended like displayed.

```
        success: function( data ) {

            response( $.map( data.list1, function( item ){

            alert("shiftid"+item.shift_id);
                return {
                    label: item.empname,
                    value: item.empname,

                    id : item.email
                    +"("
                    +item.phone
                    +"("
                    +item.shift_id
                    /*+"("
                    +item.shiftname*/
                    +"("
                    +item.empdepartment
                    +"("
                    /*+item.deptname
                    +"("*/
                    +item.emplocation
                    +"("
                    +item.empid
                    +"("
                    +item.employeetype
                    +"("
                    +item.empaddress
                    +"("
                    +item.empdesignation
                    }
            }));
        }

    });
},
minLength: 1,
select: function(event, ui ) {

    var vals = ui.item.id.split("(");


         $("#name").val(ui.item.label);
         $("#email").val(vals[0]);
            $("#phone").val(vals[1]);           
            $("#shiftid").val(vals[2]);

            $("#dept").val(vals[3]);
            $("#location").val(vals[4]);
            $("#empid1").val(vals[5]);
            $("#emptype").val(vals[6]);
            $("#address").val(vals[7]);
            $("#designation").val(vals[8]);
```

please suggest me correct answer what i require changes

Comment: i`m not sure what your trying to do in success block, but i  thing i can observe is that you havent closed the angular braces `)` properly

Comment: @dreamweiver am adding everything but am editing only some code